# Excel Dashboard Bloat: Multiple pivot charts based on single pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, dashboard, pivot-chart

Goal: I am trying to build a dashboard in excel using one pivot-table & multiple charts based on that pivot-table. The pivot-table have to have a access query data link.

Problem: Currently I build a data link for every chart because I cant find a way to build multiple charts of one pivot table. Excels bloats like a balloon when I do this and takes really long to save any changes not to mention refreshing the data...
Is there a better way of doing this? 
What do you guys use to build reports in big databases?

*Side Note: I realize Access also got pivots but they are limited in features and unstable with lots of data. Also I have seen similar questions on this site but with limited or lacking answers.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nfJLz5rVmo

Basically when working with external data you should link "un-pivoted" data then create 2 pivot tables based on that data in a new excel sheet. Then on those 2 new pivot tables you can then build 2 charts which are linked but can have different layouts!